# Edit Script Output with Stylesheet

Tags: php, stylesheet

How are you?
I have a problem with the output of an internal webpage I use to print a query. It is ultimately just a formatting problem with the output.
The actual script (get_data.php) should do nothing more than to create an output for a certain topic or for a certain category (for example, records with the value "DVD" or books of an author).
That's exactly what it's supposed to do.
Now I have the problem that when I create the output this is not displayed correctly.
The actual text block sits one line below the bullet point. This is not earth-shattering but it does not look quite so pretty, so I would like to fix it. ;)

The website uses some stylesheets to give it their formatting, but the bullets or the list are generated by script. But I'm standing in front of the mountain and can not continue with this "formatting problem".

Can you help me?
Many thanks in advance

Dennis

PS: I hope my english isn't to bad.

Comment: Simply use your own CSS rules to overwrite the existing CSS rules that are generated by the server. If you give them more specificity, yours will be the ones that get applied. There's no need to edit the PHP itself; PHP gets processed **before** it is outputted to the DOM.

Comment: Some of your PHP code or CSS might help.

Comment: @ObsidianAge 
Ok, so I can just set a command in the css to tell the script to "not make a new line"? 
Any clue which Command that could be? 
If you need any of my sourcecode just give me a comment here then I will upload some ( first have to figure out which parts might be the interesting ones) ;)